# Meta WhatsApp Client Localization Request Body not working in my Webhook code as prescribed in the Doc

Tags: facebook, nodejs-server, facebook-webhooks, whatsapi

I have a nodejs bot and a method which helps me send client a request for their location using a special Meta Whatsapp body as prescribed in the section **Location Request Messages** of [Sending Interactive Messages Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages):

Doc prescription below:

```
{
    "type": "location_request_message",
    "body": {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "<TEXT>"
    },
    "action": {
        "name": "send_location" 
    }
}
```

Wrapping component of the code above according to the doc (doc says you have to add the above code inside of the interactive property of the blow code):

```
{
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to" : "whatsapp-id", // WhatsApp ID of your recipient
    "type": "interactive",
    "interactive":{
        // Your interactive object  
    }
}
```

My own code is below (I combined the 2 above codes in one as prescribed by the doc):

```
  const body = {
      recipient_type: "individual",
      to: "mobile_number", // WhatsApp ID of your recipient
      type: "interactive",
      interactive:{
         // Your interactive object  
         type: "location_request_message",
         body: {
             type: "text",
             text: "Finally"
             // text: "Good day"
         },
         action: {
             name: "send_location" 
         }
      }
  }
```

And i send it with axios with my promise:

```
return new Promise((next) => {
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };

    AxiosService.post(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/${VERSION}/${JC_PHONE_ID}/messages`,
       body,
       headers
    )
    .then((response) => {
        // console.log("THIS RESPONSE IS REALLY BIG: ", response)
        if (response.status == 200) {
            console.log(response.status)
            next({ success: true, status: 200 });
        } else {
            console.log(response.status)
            console.log("Heehehehe....")
            next({ success: false, status: 400 });
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        next({ success: false, status: 400 });
    });
});
```

Finally sending a request for it using my webhook link:

> https://0852-154-72-160-109.ngrok-free.app/webhook/

At the end i get a 400 error:

I am pretty sure it is because facebook does not accept the way i set the body.

Can anyone help me on how to set the above json body properly?

Comment: have you tried Is it working in Postman?

Comment: It is actually on postman i try all my requests before anywhere else.
The rest of the json bodies on that documentation work well on postman i receive a response as message on whatsapp...but this particular one is a not working. I do not know how exactly i have to arrange it for it to work.
And that is why i am putting it out there for anyone to help.

Comment: This is only available for on-premises API, make sure you are using that.

Comment: I am not sure i get the full understanding of what you said...kindly explain further please.

Comment: @vially did you get a way around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aware there are 2 types of setups,

- cloud API

> *The Cloud API allows you to send and receive messages to and from customers using cloud-based servers owned by Meta. Since we host the API, you avoid the cost of hosting your own servers and can easily scale your business messaging.*

- on-premises API

> *The On-Premises API allow you to send and receive messages to and from customers using your own servers.*

You can read more differences [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/overview#on-premises-api-vs--cloud-api-comparison).

As I can see your request goes to the cloud API's host:

> *[https://graph.facebook.com/${VERSION}/${JC_PHONE_ID}/messages](https://graph.facebook.com/$%7BVERSION%7D/$%7BJC_PHONE_ID%7D/messages)*

And you are checking in on-premises API documentation:

> ***Location Request Messages** of [Sending Interactive Messages Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages)*

You need to refer to the cloud API documentation for the interactive type message, and there is no mention of location type in interactive, it is just supported in on-premises API setup,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages#interactive-messages
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/messages#interactive-object

Comment: The insight you shared are totally valid. I will surely look into the On-Premise Option, deeper. Many Thanks